# vim: get buffer number for unloaded buffer

Tags: vim

Suppose I have a file `C:/Users/Pedro/Desktop/foo.txt`. If I open Gvim and run `:echo bufnr('C:/Users/Pedro/Desktop/foo.txt')` it returns `-1` since the buffer is not loaded. I know I can edit the file (i.e run `execute "edit " 'C:/Users/Pedro/Desktop/foo.txt'`) and then I will obtain a buffer number with `bufnr()`. However, by editing the file, it will also become visible. So my question is: how can I get (or assign) a buffer number to a buffer that is not currently loaded in Vim without making it visible?
Equivalently: is there a way to load a vim buffer without making it visible?

Edit: I know about `:hide` but the problem with it is that it will not work on the last window on screen.

Comment: Is this specifically when no other buffers are already open?  If other buffers are open do you want to just continue displaying the last buffer?

Comment: Hi @RandyMorris. There might be other buffers open (or not). I just want to get a buffer number without altering the current window/buffer display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:badd somefile` to add `somefile` to the buffer list without leaving the current buffer.

`:argadd` does the same for the argument list.

See `:help :badd` and `:help :argadd`.